# Add space between a character in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

**Background**

I have a dataset, df. Whenever I try and rename the 'TanishaIsCool' column, I get an error: unexpected string constant. I wish to add spaces within my column name

```
TanishaIsCool   Hello
hi              hi
```

This is what I am doing:

```
df1 <- df %>% rename(Tanisha Is Cool = `TanishaIsCool` )
```

**Desired output**

```
 Tanisha Is Cool     Hello
 hi                  hi
```

**dput**

```
structure(list(TanishaIsCool = structure(1L, .Label = "hi", class = "factor"), 
Hello = structure(1L, .Label = "hi", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Comment: You need to put the ` backticks around the non-valid name that has spaces - `df1 <- df %>% rename(\`Tanisha Is Cool\` = TanishaIsCool)` . Otherwise the R interpreter sees `Tanisha` `is` and `Cool` as separate statements just floating there - hence the slightly cryptic "unexpected string constant"

Comment: Thank you! thelatemail - this worked too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `gsub` to capture the lower case letter (`([a-z])`), then the upper case (`([A-Z])`) and in the replacement, use the backreference of the captured groups (`\\1,`\2`) and create  space between them

```
colnames(df1) <- gsub("([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2", colnames(df1))
df1
#  Tanisha Is Cool Hello
#1              hi    hi
```

---

With `tidyverse` and option is

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
df1 %<>%
    rename_all(~ str_replace_all(., "([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2"))
```

For selected columns, use `rename_at`

```
df1 %<>%
    rename_at(1, ~ str_replace_all(., "([a-z])([A-Z])", "\\1 \\2"))
```

---

Another option is regex lookaround

```
gsub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", " ", names(df1), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Tanisha Is Cool" "Hello"
```

---

If we need to update only selected column names, then use an index, hre it is the first column

```
names(df1)[1] <- gsub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", " ", names(df1)[1], perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: thank you Akrun. I have multiple columns, and only want to add spaces in one. Do I need to specify that column?

Comment: @Lynnette Only column names that have this specific pattern will get affeected.  Or if you just wanted to change only for specific column, select that column i.e. `gsub("(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])", " ", names(df1)[1], perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Same person - I just changed my name due to someone downvoting some of my questions (not sure why) I shall change it back

Answer (score 3):

Your attempt was nearly there, except missing the backquotes/backticks:

```
df1 %>% rename(`Tanisha Is Cool` = TanishaIsCool)
```

However, I believe you will find that most recommendations (and I agree completely after my own personal experience of struggling with one particular dataset...), state not to use spaces in your variable names, since you might find that when you have to reference these variables, you will have to always include the `` , which can get pretty cumbersome.

Just realised @thelatemail has answered exactly this in the comment!